# What property will return the caret (or cursor type bar) to the designated textbox in VBA Excel UserForms?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Since most of my triggers for my userform objects are `AfterUpdate` events, the error will only occur when the user clicks on another field. However, when the error happens, the caret (or cursor) will not go back to the field where the error occurred--making the user have to click back to that field. What code can I use to bring back the caret (or cursor type bar) automatically when the error triggers?

`SetFocus` does not work because the `AfterUpdate` event fires first before the caret (or cursor type bar) moves to where the user clicks. So what happens is when the `AfterUpdate` error fires, the caret will move back to the textbox I want the caret to move to, then after the `AfterUpdate` code runs, it will go to where the user clicked at.

Comment: use `SetFocus` .

Comment: @cyboashu I think it's part of the solution, but is not working on my application as it should please refer to the updated post above

Comment: instead of `AfterUpdate` use `Exit` event.